# Tailwindcss classes not working with React(Vite)

Tags: reactjs, web, tailwind-css

So, I use Vite for the CLI and Tailwindcss for the styling. This weird problem, when the tailwind transpiler just stopped transpiling but without the process stopping too. I usually can ignore these problem. But as my projects grows, of course I need more utility classes, and the broken transpiler problem started to become a headache for me. I am really sorry if the question isn't too clear, this is because I'm sleepy when writing this.

This is the contents of my **tailwind.config.js**

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "src/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx,html}",
    "index.html",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        "main": "#00be73",
        "main-secondary": "#3BA166",
        "main-tertiary": "rgb(134, 239, 172)",
        "success": "#00be73",
        "success-secondary": "#3ba166",
        "danger": "#d70000",
        "danger-secondary": "#9C1B1B",
        "sub": "#808080",
        "sub-active": "#666666",
        "sub-secondary": "#E6E6E6",
        "sub-secondary-active": "#CCCCCC",
        "sub-tertiary": "#FFFFFF",
        "warning": "#FFE100",
        "warning-secondary": "#BFA900",
        "info": "#66baff",
        "info-secondary": "#0070cc",
      }
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

I use the default for Vite

I tried a lot of times restarting the transpiler and the server, refreshing the page didn't work. A Google search don't give too much insights. The import is also correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems with the content array path

> "src/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx,html}"

1. with the current path files in src that ends in one of the given extensions will be matched so src/SomeComponent.js will match but src/components/SomeComponent.js will not match.
2. if you are using the default vite layout as mentioned then you need to add ./ to specify same directory

FIX:

```
"./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx,html}"
```

here we added ** to tell tailwind to match any file within any subdirectory in src folder and ./ to specify it should search for src folder in current directory